# Am I Doing User Validation Right?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When user submits, project goes thru validation. Really the issues I was having was with the `If` statements. Did I do them right / is there any way to do that part better?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check Input for Validation

    //Mass Validation ensure everything has a vaule
    if (txtFirstName.Text == "" && txtLastName.Text == "" && txtPayRate.Text == ""
        && txtStartDate.Text == "" && txtEndDate.Text == "")
    {
        txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        return;
    }

    if (txtFirstName.Text != "")
    {
        txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        return;
    }

    if (txtLastName.Text != "")
    {
        txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        return;
    }

    if (txtPayRate.Text != "")
    {
        txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        return;
    }

    Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
    Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
    Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
    Response.Redirect("frmPersonnelVerified.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of context: what do you want to validate and what actions you want to take in case of success / failure? Right now we have to guess from your code, so it's not easy to know whether you are doing it right :)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBoxes = new[] { txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtPayRate, txtStartDate, txtEndDate };
    var isValid = true;

    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        if (textBox.Text == "")
        {
            isValid = false;
            textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
    }

    if (!isValid)
        return;

    Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
    Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
    Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
    Response.Redirect("frmPersonnelVerified.aspx");
}
```

But, looks like this is ASP.NET site, so **you should probably use [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.**

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this instead:

```
TextBox[] boxes = new[] { txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtPayRate,
                          txtStartDate, txtEndDate };

IEnumerable<TextBox> unfilledBoxes = boxes.Where(b => b.Text == "");

foreach (TextBox box in unfilledBoxes)
{
    box.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
}

if (!unfilledBoxes.Any())
{
    Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
    Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
    Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
    Response.Redirect("frmPersonnelVerified.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is ASP.NET WebForms, which your code implies, you should be using [Web Forms Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/465kys5b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).